# How to tell whether I'm running locally on google app engine/go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm aware of `if 'APPENGINE_RUNTIME' in os.environ.keys():` for the python runtime, but is there a similar way to tell whether I'm running locally using go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [IsDevAppServer](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine#IsDevAppServer) to determine if the application is running locally.

Comment: I can accept this answer in 12 minutes.